# How can I select the correct number?

Tags: primes

I am given a  list of prime numbers in a sorted order. The size of the list can be minimum '5' or maximum '10'.

Example list:- '2,5,7,11,29' .

I also have a machine which I can use only for 1 time.

I have to select any prime number (say x) from the list and give it as the input to machine.

Machine will give the output of x^2 modulo P . (Only machine knows the value of 'P' and it is a fixed value)

Where , 'P' is the prime number I have to guess.

One more important property:- 'P' is always a prime number which belongs to the list. 
How can I find the correct value which machine knows but I don't ?

Comment: I would ask this on math.stackexchange. Isn't it related to quadratic residues?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I don't have any idea of quadratic residues . Can you tell me the approach to solve it ? On math.stack.... I get lots of down-votes, so I posted  it here :(

Comment: The statement of the problem looks strange. But anyway, why not just try each prime Q from your small list and compute x^2 mod Q until you get an output that matches what the machine gave you?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Can you explain your words by an example...You may use the example of my question itself.

Comment: I can give machine only one number say, I chose 29 from the list and ....say Q=7(which I don't know...only machine knows the value of Q) so 27%Q=29%7=1...All I know is '1'....now how can I find the value of 'Q;' ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן My other idea is what James said.... just pre-compute everything like:- every (prime number)^2 modulo Q(all possible Q's) .... now...I am worried what if few of those values match.... if  7^2%29 is same as 7^2%2 , then...

Comment: @JamesKPolk  Thaks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example set, {2,5,7,11,29},  choosing either 5 or 7 to be `x` would provide a set of unique, telling results for `x^2 mod P`, where `P` is a prime in the example set. The set of results for 5 is {1, 0, 4, 3, 25}; and for 7, it's {1, 4, 0, 5, 20}.

Comment: Everything is perfect...... I am just worried what I would do if my set looked like this :- {1,0,1,2,3} ..... 2 numbers having same modulo.

Comment: I'll try to generate sets for each number, I hope at-least one set out of them has all distinct elements.

Comment: How would you solve for this example:- 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19

Comment: @sdrtgghytui I don't know. For 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 it looks like a few `x`s leave ambiguity only for P 2 or 3.